# Error while trying show crystal report on ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

I got this error when i try to show it

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

This is my first web application with ASP.NET. And i have a big problem to show asp.net. When i tried to send Crystal - Report via mail i get this error.

> An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

is there any way to solve this problem ? Thanks .

Comment: What version of CR do you specify in your webconfig?

Comment: @PatrickDeveloper i use CR for VS 13.0

Comment: What runtime did you download from SAP? For instance, I use (v. 13.0.2.x) and have specified this in my webconfig with <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, etc.

Comment: @PatrickDeveloper  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>

Comment: Yes that looks okay, from programs and features, find your CR for visual studios and find what version you have installed. The correct version with that assembly should be 13.0.2.469

Comment: If that is all correct, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be because you are running your application with an x64 configuration.

From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82e23647-7116-424b-b437-df0cb2be083d/an-error-has-occurred-while-attempting-to-load-the-crystal-reports-runtime):

'Go to your application project, right click, and select "Properties"

On the Build tab, find the Platform Target combo box. It probably says, "Any CPU". Change this to x86 and your project will compile for 32 bit only, thus eliminating the issue.'

Answer (score 1):

- **Application-level setting:**
- Go to IIS Click on “Application Pools”
- Select the application you want to modify (e.g.: SuperApp)
- Right click on that application
- Left click on Advanced Settings
- Set Enable 32-Bit Applications to “True”